# How can I debug SSL traffic between nginx and an Apache backend with a pre-master key?

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache-2.4, wireshark

I am trying to troubleshoot 502 Bad Gateway errors logged by nginx (used as a load balancer) when communicating with our back-end Apache application servers. The nginx `proxy_pass` module is being used to configure nginx as a reverse proxy to a cluster of Apache servers, and when capturing traffic via `tcpdump` I am unable to decrypt the HTTPS communication between nginx and Apache because the cyphersuite in Wireshark is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and I do not have the ephemeral Diffie-Hellman pre-master key.

(The issue I am trying to debug is "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" seen in nginx error log when there's *no* corresponding error in the Apache logs, making me suspect network issues causing the connection to be closed prematurely, or something)

Is there a way to make Nginx nog the Diffie-Hellman pre-master key when communicating with a `proxy_pass` backend over SSL? If not, is there any way to decrypt / debug this traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Since you control everything here why not just change it to a plaintext HTTP connection and try to repeat the issue?

Alternatively change to a simpler non-DHE cipher.

Comment: I can't change to HTTP as this violates company security policy. Changing to a non-DHE cipher is what I am going to try next, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881039/how-to-read-ssl-tls-encrypted-alert-code-under-ephemeral-rsa